# Using postgres_ext with postgis adapter not working with array columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, postgis, postgres-ext

I've successfully installed PostGIS and using the `postgres_ext` gem to add support  Rails `postgis` ActiveRecord adapter, but when I try to use a Postgres array column type in my migration, it fails:

```
t.string :pets, :array => true, :limit => 12
```

And the error:

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

    undefined method `array' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ColumnDefinition:0x007fa8357b3308>
    /Users/avishai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:36:in `try'
    /Users/avishai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/postgres_ext-0.0.9/lib/postgres_ext/active_record/connection_adapters/postgres_adapter.rb:197:in `add_column_options!'
    /Users/avishai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:38:in `add_column_options!'
    /Users/avishai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:31:in `to_sql'
    /Users/avishai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-postgis-adapter-0.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgis_adapter/spatial_table_definition.rb:76:in `block in to_sql'
    /Users/avishai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-postgis-adapter-0.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgis_adapter/spatial_table_definition.rb:76:in `map'
    /Users/avishai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-postgis-adapter-0.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgis_adapter/spatial_table_definition.rb:76:in `to_sql'
    /Users/avishai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-postgis-adapter-0.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgis_adapter/main_adapter.rb:192:in `create_table'
    /Users/avishai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
    /Users/avishai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
    /Users/avishai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
    /Users/avishai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
```

Gemfile:

```
gem "rails", "~> 3.2.9"
gem "airbrake"
gem "pg"
gem "postgres_ext"
gem "activerecord-postgis-adapter"
gem "activerecord-postgres-array", "~> 0.0.8"
```

Any idea ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

[This is a known issue](https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext/issues/39). The problem is that activerecord-postgis-adapter and postgres_ext have competing patches to the PostgreSQL adapter in ActiveRecord and the solution to this is to have either postgres_ext or activerecord-postgis-adapter depend on the other gem. It does not make sense to have postgres_ext depend on activerecord-postgis-adapter, since you do not have to use PostGIS to use the native data types of PostgreSQL

(I am the maintainer of the postgres_ext gem, and I just noticed you are the one that opened the linked issue)